# How can I make letter detection in a Hangman game?

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to create a basic hangman game using the `random` and `tkinter` libraries.

**1.** The goal of the program is to choose one random word (from an array).

**2.** Then the program replaces the letters in the word with "_".

**3.** This word will start falling down from the top edge to the bottom edge using an animation.

**4.** While the word is falling down, our goal is to guess the right word by pressing letters on the keyboard.

**5.** If the letter we've pressed is in the word the program picked, the '_' gets replaced with the letter.

So far I've created the canvas, the animation, replaced the letters with underscores, and created an array of words from where the program can pick.

How can I make the letter detection? For an instance, if I press "**F**" and the letter is in the word the program has picked, the '_' should get replaced with the letter.

My code so far

```
import random
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(height=550,width=550)
canvas.pack()

words_list = random.choice(['tkinter','patko','danko','rybar','Roosevelt','Prezident'])
x = 0
y = 0


words_list_underscore = ' _ ' * len(words_list)
  
def text() :
  global y
  canvas.delete('all')
  canvas.create_text(x+60,y+10, text=words_list_underscore)
  y = y+5
  if y<550:
        canvas.after(50, text)
text()
```

Comment: You could do what you want by "binding" an event-handler function to key-presses, and in the function check to see of the key is a letter in the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind event `<Key>` with function which will check what was pressed and it will replace text on canvas.

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.bind('<Key>', on_key_press)  # function's name without `()`

def on_key_press(event):  # tkinter runs it with event
    print('pressed:', event.char)
```

---

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def text() :
    global y
  
    canvas.move(text_on_canvas, 0, 5)
  
    y += 5
  
    if y < 550:
        canvas.after(50, text)

def on_key_press(event):
    global word_underscore
    
    char = event.char
    print('pressed:', char)
    
    if char in word.lower():
        
        count = word.count(char)
        start = 0
        
        print('count:', count)
        
        for _ in range(count):

            pos = word.find(char, start)
            word_underscore_pos = pos*3 + 1

            before = word_underscore[:word_underscore_pos]
            after  = word_underscore[word_underscore_pos+1:]
            word_underscore = before + word[pos] + after  # original size
            #word_underscore = before + char + after      # lowercase

            start = pos + 1
            
        print('new:', word_underscore)
        
        canvas.itemconfigure(text_on_canvas, text=word_underscore)
            
# --- main ---

x = 0
y = 0

word = random.choice(['tkinter','patko','danko','rybar','Roosevelt','Prezident'])
word_underscore = ' _ ' * len(word)

print(word)

# -

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=550, width=550)
canvas.pack()

root.bind('<Key>', on_key_press)

text_on_canvas = canvas.create_text(60, 10, text=word_underscore, anchor='nw')
  
text()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in a comment you need to define a event-handler function and bind it to keypress events. Since @furas' answer shows the basics of how to do that, I decided to post my own to illustrate how to do it in a more object-oriented way, which is more modular and eliminates the need for most of the global variables required in the procedure-oriented approach.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


class Hangman(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, words, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent, height=550, width=550)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.word = random.choice(words)
        self.letters = [char for char in self.word]
        print(self.word)

        self.guesses = ['_' for _ in self.word]
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.text_object = self.canvas.create_text(self.x+60, self.y+10, text=self.guesses)
        self.parent.bind('<Key>', self.keypress_handler)  # Bind event handler function.
        self.text()  # Start game animation.

    def text(self):
#        # For testing purposes to prevent hanging.
#        if self.y > 150:
#            self.canvas.after(150, self.text)
#            return

        self.canvas.move(self.text_object, 0, 5)

        self.y += 5
        if self.y < 550:
            self.canvas.after(150, self.text)
        else:
            self.end_game('You were hanged')

    def keypress_handler(self, event):
        char = event.char  # The character pressed.
        if char in self.word:  # Update any occurrences in word.
            posn = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    posn = self.letters.index(char, posn)  # Get index of char.
                except ValueError:  # No more left.
                    break
                self.guesses[posn] = char
                posn += 1

            self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.text_object, text=self.guesses)

            # See if number of correctly guessed letter equals length of word.
            if len(self.word) == sum(char != '_' for char in self.guesses):
                self.end_game('You won')  # All letters guessed correctly.

    def end_game(self, status):
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        self.canvas.create_text(275, 275, text=f'Game over: {status}!')
        self.parent.bell()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = 'tkinter', 'patko', 'danko', 'rybar', 'Roosevelt', 'President'

    root = tk.Tk()
    Hangman(root, words).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```